# Go с чего начинаются файлы в пакете fmt?

Tags: golang

Изучаю Golang, читаю книгу в которой задан вопрос:
"Наша программа начиналась с package main. С чего начинаются файлы в пакете fmt?"

В книге написано следующее:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main {
fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

Дано пояснение:

> Программу, которую мы только что написали, можно прочитать следующим
>   образом: Создать новую исполняемую программу, которая использует
>   библиотеку fmt и содержит функцию main. Эта функция не имеет
>   аргументов, ничего не возвращает и делает следующее: использует
>   функцию Println из библиотеки fmt и вызывает её, передавая один
>   аргумент — строку Hello World. Функция Println выполняет основную
>   работу в этой программе.

Правильно ли я понимаю что файлы в пакете fmt начинаются с функций, в данном случае с  "Println"?

Answer (score 2):

import - импортирует пакет по имени. А package указывает имя пакета и пишется в самом верху. Поэтому, пакет fmt должен начинаться с строки `package fmt` или комментариев, после которых будет эта строка.

Comment: Думаю, раз уж вы упомянули комментарии, можно и про [метки сборки](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) упомянуть.